# ASP.NET(4.5) GridView Paging HTML Markup Missing href Links

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I have a correctly working `asp:GridView` on one page of my ASP.Net WebForms application, and an incredibly similar one on another page that is not working. The issue is with the paging; I have `AllowPaging=true` on the `asp:GridView` control and a correctly set up `OnPageIndexChanging="searchResultsGridView_PageIndexChanging"` method in the code-behind. When run, the paging displays correctly (even with my custom css on the `PagerStyle`) but the numbered link-buttons for the subsequent pages do not have any `href=""` set up on in the markup that is generated.

Here is the generated markup:

```
<tr align="center" class="gridViewPager">
        <td colspan="10">
          <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <span>1</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a>2</a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a>3</a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a>4</a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a>5</a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a>6</a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a>7</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Obviously there should be an `href=""` property on the `<a>` tags for each `<td>` but there isn't. Here is the markup from the page that has a correctly working paging `asp:GridView`:

```
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ModalPanelContentPlaceholder$designerSearchResultsGridView','Page$2')">2</a></td>
```

Here is my .aspx code:

```
<div id="searchResultsTableGridViewDivContainer" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered" ID="searchResultsGridView"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="info"
            OnRowDataBound="searchResultsGridView_RowDataBound"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="searchResultsGridView_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowPaging="true"
            PageSize="15" OnPageIndexChanging="searchResultsGridView_PageIndexChanging"
            runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tracking #" DataField="TrackingNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Product Type" DataField="ProductType.TypeName" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Design Type" DataField="DesignType.TypeName" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PWA #" DataField="PWAProductNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PWB #" DataField="PWBProductNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Rev" DataField="Revision" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Designers" DataField="DesignersCSV" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status.StatusName" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="# Times Released" DataField="NumTimesReleased" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Queue Date" DataField="FormattedQueueDate" />
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="gridViewPager" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

And my relevant codebehind:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// EVENT HANDLER: Handles the RowDataBound event of the customerSearchResultsGridView control.
    /// 
    /// Allow the entire row to be clicked as a "Selector".
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="GridViewRowEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected void searchResultsGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] =
                ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(searchResultsGridView, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
    }

    protected void searchResultsGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aboutProductBtnPanel.Enabled = (searchResultsGridView.SelectedRow == null) ? false : true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// EVENT HANDLER: Handles the PageIndexChanging event of the searchResultsGridView control.
    /// 
    /// Increment the next page of the GridView for results > 15.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="GridViewPageEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected void searchResultsGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        searchResultsGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

        // don't refetch the data, just get it from the session
        searchResultsGridView.DataSource = SessionWrapper.Current.CaptureProductSearchResults;
        searchResultsGridView.DataBind();

        // new page, clear the selection
        searchResultsGridView.SelectedIndex = -1;
        aboutProductBtnPanel.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Any idea why the auto-generated HTML markup would fail to add the href links?

Comment: Just to compare, can you also post the working GridView's markup?

Comment: What is your `searchFormView` object? All of your other references to searchResultsGridView do not have this prefix. Can you try removing it on this line: `searchFormView.SearchResultsGridView.DataBind();`

Comment: Ah, @gotmilk13531, I originally had the content of the `searchResultsGridView_PageIndexChanging()` method in an external presenter class since my application followed the MVP design pattern. To simplify the code shown, I copied the content of the external presenter's helper method into the event method from the code-behind, but forgot to rid myself of the handle to the view that the presenter had. Sorry about the confusion, but the `searchFormView` should not be, and is not, involved in the issue. I since updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: @Andrei, the HTML markup that is shown with the `javascript:__doPostBack(...` is directly from the correctly working GridView markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was a stray line that was setting the `searchResultsGridView.Enabled = false;`. Therefore, ASP.NET still causes the markup of the pages to be rendered, but to "disable" the `asp:GridView`, it just cleverly leaves out the `href=""` of each `<a>` tag.

Whelp, that was a waste of a few hours. Thanks for your time, @gotmilk13531 and @Andrei.